# Next JS 14.0.1 - Cannot get final name for export 'encodeXML' of ./node_modules/entities/lib/esm/index.js

Tags: npm, next.js, vercel, netlify

So I am trying to deploy my portfolio website to Vercel or Netlify and I am facing this issue.
It's the same for Vercel as well as Netlify

```
[23:18:24.904] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive)
[23:18:25.024] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[23:18:25.448] Previous build cache not available
[23:18:25.726] Downloading 51 deployment files...
[23:18:26.417] Running "vercel build"
[23:18:26.942] Vercel CLI 32.5.2
[23:18:27.337] Installing dependencies...
[23:18:39.394] 
[23:18:39.395] added 419 packages in 12s
[23:18:39.395] 
[23:18:39.396] 140 packages are looking for funding
[23:18:39.396]   run `npm fund` for details
[23:18:39.418] Detected Next.js version: 14.0.1
[23:18:39.422] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+
[23:18:39.422] Running "npm run build"
[23:18:42.418] 
[23:18:42.419] > kaustubhdev@0.1.0 build
[23:18:42.419] > next build
[23:18:42.419] 
[23:18:43.265] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[23:18:43.265] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[23:18:43.265] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[23:18:43.266] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[23:18:43.266] 
[23:18:43.489]    ▲ Next.js 14.0.1
[23:18:43.490]    - Environments: .env
[23:18:43.491] 
[23:18:43.492]    Creating an optimized production build ...
[23:18:53.589] Failed to compile.
[23:18:53.590] 
[23:18:53.590] ./node_modules/html-to-text/lib/html-to-text.mjs + 24 modules
[23:18:53.590] Cannot get final name for export 'encodeXML' of ./node_modules/entities/lib/esm/index.js
[23:18:53.590] 
[23:18:53.591] 
[23:18:53.592] > Build failed because of webpack errors
[23:18:53.636] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[23:18:53.840]
```

And when I try to build manually I get this error

```
 Failed to compile.
./node_modules/html-to-text/lib/html-to-text.mjs + 24 modules
  Cannot get final name for export 'encodeXML' of ./node_modules/entities/lib/esm/index.js
Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I am sharing My Package.json file for a better understanding

```
    {
  "name": "kaustubhdev",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-email/components": "^0.0.11",
    "@react-email/tailwind": "^0.0.12",
    "next": "14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "resend": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

This issue persists even if try to deploy the website using GitHub or directly by CLI

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/resendlabs/resend-node/issues/256) is the link to the bug, mentioned in another answer.

The following fixes the issue

Before:

```
const html = MagicLinkEmail({ url, host });

await resend.emails.send({
  from: env.RESEND_EMAIL_FROM,
  to: params.identifier,
  subject: `Log in to ${host}`,
  html: html,
});
```

After:

```
import { renderAsync } from '@react-email/render'

const html = await renderAsync(MagicLinkEmail({ url, host }));

await resend.emails.send({
  from: env.RESEND_EMAIL_FROM,
  to: params.identifier,
  subject: `Log in to ${host}`,
  html: html,
});
```

Comment: Hi, for me, emails sent using these are visible as pure HTML, it's unreadable

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug related to the Resend Email SDK Version 2
So the best way to deal with this is to downgrade to Version 1.

People have already raised PR on GitHub